# error " the type or namespace FirebaseClient" could not be found in Android Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I already add package **Xamarin.Firebase.Database**. But any way the app keep going to give that error. And I tried to type namespace "`using Firebase.Database`;" but it doesn't want recognize the `FirebaseClient`? Is there any solution?

Comment: What tutorial are you trying to follow? I think you installed the wrong package, you probably trying to use some third-party lib.

Comment: thank you for feedback. It seems I had have to install Xamarin.Firebase